# Swift 3 Send HTTP Request Result to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, httprequest

I am sending an HTTP request.  If the result is successful, I want it to show up on a second UIViewController.  However, if it fails, I want display the failure on the original UIViewController.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "x": 2,
        "y": 2
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
            let secondViewController:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
            self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            let jsonVar: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            secondViewController.jsonDisplayResult.text = "\(jsonVar)"
        } else {
            self.jsonDisplayError.text = "no response"
        }
    }
```

I have created the second ViewController already and a label to display the result as well.  I am receiving this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb).

Comment: What is the context where you're invoking the request method of Alamofire?

Comment: Two integers are passed in as parameters.  The POST request will return the sum of the two integers.  If one integer is null then it will return Invalid Response

Comment: Which line did it crash on? Was it let jsonVar: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!) . If so its because response.result.value is nil and ! means not nil.

Comment: It crashes on this line: "secondViewController.jsonDisplayResult.text = "\(jsonVar)""

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint at `secondViewController.jsonDisplayResult.text = "\(jsonVar)"` and upload a screenshot of the Debug Navigator?

Comment: Breakpoint gives this: (lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
    if let response = response.result.value as? <insert Type of value> {
        let secondViewController:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.responseText = response
        self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        self.jsonDisplayError.text = "no response"
    }
}
```

and also create a new var `responseText` in your secondViewController and assign the `jsonDisplayResult.text = resonseText` in viewDidLoad, because your `jsonDisplayResult` Label is prob. nil at the state where you try to assign the text property to it.

Comment: I was able to get it to go to the next screen.  However, nothing is appearing in the UILabel field.

Comment: at which point you are assigning the label.text (viewDidLoad)?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `jsonDisplayResult` is a `UILabel` or `UITextField` or something of the sort, hooked up via `IBOutlet`, and it's nil because you've instantiated your `secondViewController` as `SecondViewController()`, which won't set any of the outlets.

Try instantiating from the storyboard.  Make sure to set the identifier correctly in the storyboard.

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
```

**EDIT:**

After clicking on your `SecondViewController` set the Storyboard ID here:

[image]

Comment: I am getting "implicit use of self in closure; use self."  When I switch to self I get "Value of type ViewController has no member instantiateViewController"

Comment: 2017-02-16 10:46:08.132 HTTPRequest[36936:289563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x60800007fec0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SecondViewController''

Comment: I quote: "Make sure to set the identifier correctly in the storyboard."

Comment: I fixed the Storyboard ID and I'm getting this error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"